# The use of the verb "authenticate" in context

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Could you tell me if I used the verb authenticate correctly in the sentence below?

> Before I can give you your PIN code, I have to **authenticate** you first.

The context is a customer calls his cell phone carrier customer support and asks for his PIN number. To get it he has to prove that they are the owner of the phone.

If the word *authenticate* doesn't work there, can I use *verify*? For example:

> Before I can give you your PIN code, I have to **verify**  you first.

Comment: Come on now, you can look that up very easily. authenticate and verify are not the same thing. authentication is an online "thing" to make sure the person has the email and phone, and User ID for example, associated with an account. authentication is an internet term here. Obviously, if some is authenticated, you have "verified" who they are based on an online presence or back and forth.

Comment: Yes, I looked it up and dictionaries disagree with what you say said. This one, for example, says that "authenticate" means that something is true or real. It doesn't say anything about online https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/authenticate

Comment: Also, if you say that "authenticate" doesn't work there, would you be kind enough to say if it's natural to say "verify YOU",  like "I have verify you" before giving your PIN"?

Comment: If you read your first comment carefully, you'll see that you only pointed out the difference between "authenticate" and "verify"

Comment: Good job editing the comment. Yes, in my original answer I asked if it was natural to use "authenticate" in the context, if not, if it would be natural to use "verify" instead. Your gave me your take on and I really appreciated. Then in my third comment I asked whether or not it would be natural to use it with "you". You said, in your third comment, you had told me already, which you hadn't. And now you edit it leaving me without an answer to the question I asked in my second comment that you claimed to give me in your first comment. Not cool man, not cool.

Comment: I hope these 2 sentences from Cambridge dictionary will help you: 1) "A password is used to authenticate a user." 2) "We offer electronic certificates that authenticate the identity of internet trades."